# How is matching theory used in context of Marriage market difference in terms of which is used in context of labour and housing market?

Tags: labor-economics, housing, search-and-matching, matching

I am looking for an overview as most of the introduction to matching talks about the work done in the Marriage market, Job Matching which is axiomatic. Then while looking at Labour and housing market it very different and at a very macro level.

Marriage: https://web.stanford.edu/~niederle/Palgrave%20Matching.Approved.pdf

Labour: https://economics.mit.edu/files/7400

Housing: http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/facbios/file/Search%20and%20Matching.pdf

Comment: The literature on what I call "matching" is concerned with the design of algorithms and allocation rules that match market participants on one side to one or many of another side. The seminal paper here is Gale and Shapley's deferred-acceptance paper on the marriage market.
The macro literature on "search and matching" is a very different animal, where the matching technology is given (its not about the design) and equilibrium is analyzed.

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. :)